# Ошибка AH00112 при настройке git по http

Tags: apache, git, http

Сервер с `ubuntu 14.04`
На сервере установлено:

```
git
gitolite
apache2
```

На сервер попадаю по адресу `http://gitserver/`

Репозитории на сервере находятся по пути `/home/git/repositories`

В `/home/git/repositories` есть пустой репозиторий `test`

В конфигурационный файл apache по пути `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` в конец были добавлены строки:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /home/git/repositories
ServerName gitserver

<Directory "/home/git/repositories">
Allow from All
Options +ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
</Directory>

SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/git/repositories
ScriptAlias /git /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend
</VirtualHost>
```

После команды:

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

вылетает ошибка:

```
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/etc/apache2/home/git/repositories] does not exist
```

Comment: возможно, где-то в конфигурации есть другие упоминания `home/git/...`. попробуйте закомментировать блок virtualhost и проверить конфигурацию: `$ sudo apache2ctl configtest`

Comment: Брал информацию здесь http://www.parallelsymmetry.com/howto/git.jsp#suexec  в разделе Base Configuration. Там больше ничего не было

Comment: Закоментировал блок virtualhost ввел `$ sudo apache2ctl configtest`. Вот что выдало `AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Syntax OK`

Comment: это нормально. расскомментируйте и проверьте, не затесалось ли между `/` и `home` каких-нибудь нечитабельных символов. или просто набейте вручную эту строку.

Comment: это уже совершенно другой вопрос. задайте его с помощью кнопки в правом верхнем углу страницы. если необходим контекст из этого вопроса, дайте на него ссылку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скорее всего, в директиве *documentroot* пропущен <kbd>/</kbd> перед <kbd>home</kbd> (хотя не исключён вариант, что затесались какие-нибудь нечитабельные символы).